# How can I use parse_date_time() to covert my date variable to a different date-time variable?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble converting my date variable in my data frame to a new date-time variable. I know parse_date_time(x, orders="ymd HMS") but I don't know what code is needed to say: use this dataframe (workHours) and grab this column (date) now change to a new column named (date_time) and convert to "ymd HMS"
The date column already has the date and time in this format: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss and its a fct or factor.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data like this -

```
workHours <- data.frame(date = c('3/22/2020 04:51:12', '3/15/2019 10:12:32'))
workHours

#                date
#1 3/22/2020 04:51:12
#2 3/15/2019 10:12:32
```

You can use `as.POSIXct` in base R

```
workHours$date_time <- as.POSIXct(workHours$date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %T', tz = 'UTC')
```

Or `lubridate::mdy_hms`

```
workHours$date_time <- lubridate::mdy_hms(workHours$date)
```

Both of which would return -

```
#                date           date_time
#1 3/22/2020 04:51:12 2020-03-22 04:51:12
#2 3/15/2019 10:12:32 2019-03-15 10:12:32

class(workHours$date_time)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: I have a data frame that has these columns: name, branch, department, dep head, hours, date, but I'm wanting to convert the date column, which has the date and time already in it, to a new column named date-time. I want to keep the structure of the data frame so I just add a new column. This only gave me a list of the dates and times.

Comment: You don't have to use data from my example. Since you did not provide any data I created an example to show how the code works. You should use this code on the dataframe that you already have. This code keeps the structure of your dataframe and just adds a new column called `date_time` in the dataframe.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I didn't realize it would change the original data frame. I thought I had to make that into another variable then call that. I'm really new to all of this, thanks that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
workHours <- data.frame(date = c('3/22/2020 04:51:12', '3/15/2019 10:12:32'))

anytime(workHours$date)
[1] "2020-03-22 04:51:12 EDT" "2019-03-15 10:12:32 EDT"
```